Variable is not accessed Pylance
Python 3.12.5:
my_list: list[str] = ["MFI BL {num}" for num in range(1, 15)]

The num variable is clearly accessed but I have a warning that says "num" is not accessed Pylance.
Why do I have this warning:

I'm using VS Code. I do not have the warning on PyCharm.
Printing my_list does not change anything (making sure my_list ends up being used):
my_list: list[str] = ["MFI BL {num}" for num in range(1, 15)]
print(my_list)


Err… looking at what the print outputs, you should see that {num} has not in fact been interpolated…?!

num is assigned as part of the list comprehension, but is then never used. You'd get the exact same output if you replaced num with an underscore (_), so the warning seems to be correct:
my_list: list[str] = ["MFI BL {num}" for _ in range(1, 15)]
# Here ----------------------------------^

It looks like you meant to use an f-string, in which case the {num} placeholder would be evaluated, and the warning would be resolved:
my_list: list[str] = [f"MFI BL {num}" for num in range(1, 15)]
# Here ---------------^


If you think the problem is "you used a regular string when you meant to use the f-string," I'd much rather you leave a comment and VTC as "typo/norepro" instead of answering. Otherwise, the post can't be roomba-ed.
